# In R i have a column with text. How can i write a script in R that counts the frequency of the specific words?

Tags: r, count, frequency

The text column can hold up to 100 letters for each entry. How can i write a script that recognizes the word "Approved" or "Rejected". Sometimes the word will be        "-Approved", "**Approved**","Approved" or "Approve". I want it to account for each scenario with a "LIKE" type of function.

There are two words i am looking for so "OR" may be applicable to this as opposed to a range.

Comment: It would help if you had at least sample data (as a `data.frame`) and the expected output of that sample data. What have you tried? `regmatches(txt, gregexpr("approved|rejected", txt, ignore.case = TRUE))` might be a good start (potentially with `table(unlist(...))`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has a pair of text-similarity functions,  `agrep` and `agrepl`, which are like `grep` and `grepl` in returning a vector when given a vector. The agrepl function is logical and of the same length as the input so works better in cases like this:

```
 agrepl("Approved", df$text_col) | agrepl("Rejected", df$text_col)
```

That could be used to logically index matching rows of a dataframe. Or you could sum the logical vector to get a count. Suggestion: Edit your question with an example to use for demonstration.

There are additional parameters that can be used to adjust the tightness of the approximate matching.